# Seed One to many relationship in EF Core 2.0

Tags: entity-framework-core

Folks, I have the following table structure

```
public class PolicySubStatus
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PolicySubStatusId { get; set; }
    public string SubStatusName { get; set; }
    public IList<PolicySubStatusReason> PolicySubStatusReason { get; set; }        

}
public class PolicySubStatusReason
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PolicySubStatusReasonId { get; set; }
    public string SubStatusReason { get; set; }
}
```

This create the igration and update the DB correctly with the appropriate FK for one to many relationships.

My issue is seeding the data using ModelBuilder, how do I create the join in the data ?
I have this

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PolicySubStatusReason>().HasData(
            new PolicySubStatusReason
            {
                PolicySubStatusReasonId = 1,                      
                SubStatusReason = "Claim Repair Documents"

            },
         new PolicySubStatusReason
            {
                PolicySubStatusReasonId = 2,
                SubStatusReason = "Cause of Loss Statement"

            },
```

How do I go about seeding the PolicySubStatus to reference the above list of PolicySubStatusReason ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an anonymous type to represent seeded `PolicySubStatusReason` since you don't expose an FK property `PolicySubStatusReason.PolicySubStatusId`.

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<PolicySubStatus>().HasData(
        new PolicySubStatus
        {
            PolicySubStatusId = 999,
            SubStatusName = "abc"
        });

    modelBuilder.Entity<PolicySubStatusReason>().HasData(
        // anonymous type
        new
        {
            PolicySubStatusReasonId = 1,
            PolicySubStatusId = 999,
            SubStatusReason = "Claim Repair Documents"
        },
        new
        {
            PolicySubStatusReasonId = 2,
            PolicySubStatusId = 999,
            SubStatusReason = "Cause of Loss Statement"
        });
}
```